# RxJava Code Execution Flow - map vs. flatMap

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, frp

I am having a hard time trying to learn RxJava and Reactive programming while writing a Web crawler with JerseyRx and RxMongo driver. My code looks as follows:

```
    Observable.interval( 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ).map(tick -> links(linksCollection)
            .map(linkDoc -> httpGet(client, linkDoc.getString("url"))
                    .map(htmlDoc -> parseLinks(htmlDoc)).subscribe() )
            .subscribe())
    .subscribe();
```

The signatures of links() and httpGet() are as follows:

```
Observable<Document> links(MongoCollection<Document> linkCollection)
Observable<String> httpGet(RxClient<RxObservableInvoker> client, String url)
List<HtmlLink> parseLinks(final String html)
```

Suppose the methods are printing their names when they are called, then the output looks as follows:

Links
Get
Links
Parse
Links
Links
Links
Links

Get and Parse are only called one time.
Can somebody please explain why the program flow is like that and how to solve that issue.

*Objects that are not declared in that question are only left out for brevity*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to trigger an asynchronous sub-process (like fetching the http document for a link), you should use `flatMap`. It will flatten the sub-Observable and emit its items as another sequential "burst" of emissions in the output Observable:

```java
Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    //this is a continuous flow of n documents repeated every 200ms:
    .flatMap(tick -> links(linksCollection))
    //this is a continous Observable<String> with n Strings every 200ms
    .flatMap(linkDoc -> httpGet(client, linkDoc.getString("url"))
    //here you have a flow of httpDocuments, get the list of links for each one
    .map(htmlDoc -> parseLinks(htmlDoc);
```

Affecting this chain to a variable yield an `Observable<List<HtmlLink>>` to which you can subscribe.

Comment: finally i have to say that my whole problem resolved around understanding the difference between map and flatMap. Having at least partially understood that, made composing reactive flows much easier.